# adding directory name into SEF url and also passing id value without using it in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, sef

I'm a newbie about .htaccess and rewrite functions.
I've searched many pages but I couldn't find a solution.
Here's my problem:

I have urls in these formats in my kurum.php file:

```
fxrehber.com/kurum.php?id=$krmID&sef=$sef
```

so my normal url is:

**http://fxrehber.com/kurum.php?id=7&sef=ata-foreks**

related part of my .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /kurum.php?id=$1&sef=$2
</IfModule>
```

So I can get SEF urls in this format:

**http://fxrehber.com/7-ata-foreks**

I have two questions:

1 . Can this url changed into this format with .htaccess without moving kurum.php file into a new directory?

**http://fxrehber.com/kurumlar/7-ata-foreks**

(I can add "/kurumlar" directory by .htaccess but my css and image link won't work)

2 . Can I pass the id value without mentioning it in the SEF url like this:

**http://fxrehber.com/kurumlar/ata-foreks** (which is the best option for me)

If I cannot do this, do I have to use only $sef variable to select articles from the database? Is there a disadvantage about this?

I hope this is enough explanation about my problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 . Can this url changed into this format with .htaccess without moving kurum.php file into a new directory?

`http://fxrehber.com/kurumlar/7-ata-foreks`

(I can add "/kurumlar" directory by .htaccess but my css and image link won't work)

---

I used full path of the image inside php file and it works with this:
.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^kurumlar\/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /kurum.php?id=$1&sef=$2
</IfModule>
```

kurum.php:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
<img src="/sites/default/files/1.png">
```

2 . Can I pass the id value without mentioning it in the SEF url like this:

`http://fxrehber.com/kurumlar/ata-foreks` (which is the best option for me)

---

Only if `ata-foreks` can be used as a unique alias of an article and used instead of id.

> "Is there a disadvantage about this?"

Yes. Searching by string is slower, then by integer.

Comment: 1. After putting "/" before all the links, there's no problem about adding directory name to the url. (By the way, I didn't use $_REQUEST and I'm not sure if I have to)

2. I decided not to use ids, only alias..(they are not very long strings)
Thank you :)

Comment: > "By the way, I didn't use $_REQUEST and I'm not sure if I have to". You don't have to use it. I just put it into my file to make sure, that all the variables are correctly processed by .htaccess.